# Avoiding copies of large struct parameter when composing iterator methods

Tags: c#, iterator

I have a large struct that I know from profiling, is expensive to copy. I am passing instances of this struct around using the `in` keyword to great effect.

Now I want to pass this as a parameter to an iterator method, which itself passes the value to other iterator methods - but `in` is not allowed, which means the value gets copied each time it's passed to a method.

The context here is a struct containing save state for a video game, and the iterator method is a 'load' method which spreads processing of the save data over several frames, in the Unity game engine (which implements coroutines using iterators). The load method is complex so needs to be factored into several methods.

Example:

```
struct SaveData{
    // large data
}

// Async loading - can spread processing across frames (yay!) but copies lots of data (boo!)

IEnumerator LoadAsync(SaveData saveData) {// wish I could use 'in' here!
    // use some part of saveData
    yield return;
    // use more of saveData
    yield return InnerLoad(saveData); // wish I could use 'in' here!
}

IEnumerator InnerLoadAsync(SaveData saveData) {// wish I could use 'in' here!
    // use saveData
    yield return;
}


// Synchronous loading - very efficient (yay!) but blocks, causing an unacceptably long delay (boo!)

void LoadSynchronous(in SaveData saveData){
    // use some part of saveData
    // use more of saveData
    InnerLoadSynchronous(in saveData);
}

void InnerLoadSynchronous(in SaveData saveData){
    // use saveData
}
```

I understand why in general `in` is not allowed for iterators (e.g. what if the iterator/coroutine outlasted the owner of the value?) - so I can see why a copy is needed for the outermost iterator function. For the inner calls though, since they're called with `yield return`, the inner iterator won't outlast the inner, so it seems like there should be some way to use `in`.

Are there any language features I'm missing here, or perhaps a nice pattern I can use to work around it? I think wrapping the type with an outer class would work, but it seems a little messy and of course still requires one copy since I can't have a `ref` or `in` member.

Comment: If it's so big and you're passing it by-ref everywhere, you're basically treating it like a reference type that's stored somewhere other than the managed heap. Why can't it be converted to a reference type? Every bit of this screams "value type is the wrong choice."

Comment: If you need it to be a value type, you'll have to implement your `Load` method as a proper state machine, rather than relying on the compiler to generate a state machine for you. You can then pass `in SaveData` into your state machine's `MoveNext` method each time you call it.

Comment: @madreflection - "stored somewhere other than the managed heap" is a really helpful thing to say! You're right, it's crazy to keep it on the stack since it's so big. So clearly I should be wrapping it in a reference type anyway, which I can pass around without 'in'. It's not as simple as using reference types everywhere though - the outer SaveData struct will contain many many parts, and if all of them are reference types, this will contribute to heap fragmentation (it's a real observed problem, hence why I'm so into structs!). I'm aiming for a small number of large areas of memory to be used.

Comment: @canton7 Thanks! I hadn't considered this at all - I'll check if Unity supports coroutines that accept parameters to `MoveNext`, or if I can call the IEnumerator methods myself. I have a feeling that it's Unity that calls `MoveNext` but there may be a way around it.

Comment: `Unity` does call `MoveNext`, and there's no way to get the C# compiler to generate an iterator method which has a `MoveNext` method which accepts any parameters. I don't think there's any need to put `SaveData` in a wrapper class: why not just make it a class? Noone's suggesting all of its fields become classes as well.

Comment: @BenHymers: So maybe your question should be about how to redesign it as a reference type that involves minimal fragmentation, but really the wrapper class ought to do it.

Comment: Also, there are other places it could be besides the stack, which is why that comment doesn't just say "the stack". First of all, the stack is an implementation detail; even if it can't be optimized to registers, the JIT may choose to do something else in future optimizations, such as `in`-like by-ref passing. Second, there are non-stack places where a struct can be stored. Static fields are neither on the stack nor on the managed heap (not sure what that's called, but in the C++ world, that's a `.data` area), so if you were keeping a "global variable" that way, it's not on any thread's stack.

Comment: Static data goes onto the heap in .NET

Comment: Sorry @canton7, I made a bit of a jump in the discussion there to keep the comment in the character limit - the innermost parts of the load method call tree would also want to take parts of the save data as 'in' parameters too (e.g. iterating through loading each game character), so the same problem would exist there. And actually SaveData itself is already part of another struct :) I'll just have to be strategic about which things to wrap in ref types I guess.

Comment: @madreflection - not sure what you mean about rewording the question, I asked what I wanted to discover and got some good answers and comments :) Thanks!

Comment: It seemed like an XY problem. If you got what you wanted, that's great. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the inner calls though, since they're called with yield return, the inner iterator won't outlast the inner, so it seems like there should be some way to use in.

You're missing something. Let's take a simple example:

```
public class C
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var enumerator = Outer(3);

        Console.WriteLine("Enumerating 1");
        enumerator.MoveNext();

        Console.WriteLine("Enumerating 2");
        enumerator.MoveNext();

        var innerEnumerator = (IEnumerator)enumerator.Current;

        Console.WriteLine("Enumerating Inner 1");
        innerEnumerator.MoveNext();
    }
    
    public static IEnumerator Outer(int i)
    {
        yield return null;
        Console.WriteLine("Yielding Inner");
        yield return Inner(i);
    }
    
    public static IEnumerator Inner(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Inner {i}");
        yield break;   
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Enumerating 1
Enumerating 2
Yielding Inner
Enumerating Inner 1
Inner 3
```

([SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWACgKAGAAgpoDoBhCAGz4wwGAJYQ8AZwDcjWUwDM7Kq26MA3o1ZalVTdo0NtR1gDcAhlFYw8OALYwoZjNFYBeVgHkcGBwAp5AJQyhsZaHACcvgBEAKI29o6ieADmrDRRQXqh1nYOTtCcALIQJjAAcjAIGL6ZIaER0XG5iSIprFQZwaFaOQn5UEUl5ZXVtd2mFqyteA5Nfc6W7r4AknN5CwG96wXcOFCweBhd3Q2x8eutqct4M5bpY93Ts+eJBcWlFVU1x1oAvlmsAEURQcJCsVYvfqebx+VoYKYBAEGcYcGjsADsrBsAh+xlOAE0RDA+IRLuCbg5OgCjKiMeTbr4RA8/gCgSCaGCIc0odcGXCEUjqdoGgASKK8hysNQiX5Uup4mho4CwMwAayk2gB/wYvyAA=)).

As you can see, `Inner` isn't enumerated straight away. The compiler-generated implementation of `Inner` returns the compiler-generated `IEnumerable` to the caller of `Outer`, and it isn't until that caller explicitly calls `MoveNext` that the body of `Inner` is executed.

But, `Inner` was invoked much earlier. The compiler-generated implementation of `Inner` executed in full, and returned the generated `IEnumerator`, just after the `Yielding Inner` above. So `Inner` needs to store the variable `i` somewhere in a compiler-generated class, which is why it can't be `in`.

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks! Somehow I've been using IEnumerator for years but hadn't considered that the first call doesn't actually execute any code! I've just checked what Unity does and it turns out it always calls `MoveNext` once when starting a coroutine, which is probably why I didn't know this about iterators. In any case - it seems that given your answer, there isn't any way that this is going to be possible within the language, and I'll instead have to work around it by wrapping my type.

Comment: It's a well-known gotcha, and means that if you're throwing e.g. `ArgumentExceptions` from your iterator method, they won't be thrown until someone actually tries to enumerate it, which is bad. That's why most `IEnumerable`-returning methods will do argument-checking, and then do `return Inner(args)` where `Inner` is another method which uses `yield return`, to ensure that argument checks are run when the out method is called, and not when the `IEnumerable` is first enumerated